# std::atomic_thread_fence has undefined reference

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu-12.04, libstdc++

On a Ubuntu 12.04 system when I try compiling the following code:

```
#include <atomic>
int a;
int main()
{
  a = 0;
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
  a = 1;
}
```

I get an error message like:

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++0x 
/tmp/ccayKntC.o: In function `main': test.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order)' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This happens when compiling with `clang++` also.  Since it is a linker error I guess that my version of libstdc++ lacks the necessary functionality.  However, other atomic operations seem to work.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.  I'm wondering if there is a problem with my system setup, whether it is a missing feature from my libstdc++, or possibly something else. And ideally I'd like to be able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a bug which was fixed in the 4.7 branch:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51038

I think you need to use [`__sync_synchronize`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) or something like `__asm__ __volatile__ ( "mfence" ::: "memory" )`

Some people like to be very rigorous about [which synchronization operation](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html) they need, but I think using `mfence` all the time will suffice for common cases.

Comment: Thanks I installed gcc 4.7 from a PPA and that fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Unless, of course, the goal is to write code in C++ that works on any processor. :-)